# Why doesn't my table start on a new line when after my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I'm working on building a website, and I'm running into a bug. I have my navigation bar, and all that, and now I am trying to make the table go on a new line.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/topbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul class ="menu" rel="sam1">
            <li class="active"><a href="Home.htm">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Compare.htm">Compare Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="Download.htm">Download</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <td>Hi</td>
</table>

</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header
{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    background:#939393;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(168,168,168)), to(rgb(69,69,69)));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(168,168,168), rgb(69,69,69));
    border-top:1px solid #939393;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:30px;

}
body
{
    margin:0;
}
ul 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.menu 
{
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
ul.menu li 
{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:25%;
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    height:79px;
    text-align:center;
    background:-webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 100%, 10, 50% 50%, 90, from(rgba(31,169,244,1)), to(rgba(0,28,78, 1)) );
    background:-moz-radial-gradient(center 80px 45deg, circle cover, rgba(31,169,244,1) 0%, rgba(0,28,78, 1) 100%);
}

ul li a 
{
    display:block;
    padding:0 20px;
    border-left:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    text-align:center;
    line-height:79px;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(168,168,168)), to(rgb(69,69,69)));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(168,168,168), rgb(69,69,69));
    -webkit-transition-property: background;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1500ms;
    -moz-transition-property:background;
    -moz-transition-duration:1500ms;
}

ul li a:hover 
{
    background:transparent none;
}

ul li.active a
{
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 100%, 10, 50% 50%, 90, from(rgba(31,169,244,1)), to(rgba(0,28,78, 1)) );
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center 80px 45deg, circle cover, rgba(31,169,244,1) 0%, rgba(0,28,78, 1) 100%);
}
```

When I run my code, it adds a scrollbar to the bottom of my webpage, and it makes the table show up like this:

[image: Bar]

Is there any way I can fix it? And make it go to a new line?

I now I can do it really sloppy by adding 4 `<br>` tags, but I don't think that is very professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to remove:

```
float:left;
```

from:

```
ul.menu
{
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Or you could add:

```
.navbar 
{
    clear:right;

}
```

and that will remove everything to the right.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my problem! Thank you for both the options!

Answer (score 1):

Remove float:left from ul:

```
 ul.menu 
{
    height:80px;
    width:100%;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uxp4x/

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. You also had to post the jsfiddle link... :)

Answer (score 1):

I put your sample code here

http://jsbin.com/AwuwAzU/4/

and added

```
.navbar {
 clear:right;

}
```

so that the word "Hi" goes onto a new line is that want you wanted